# Magento 2 Admin Error using Mirasvit Push Notifications

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, cors, firebase

Having installed the Mirasvit Push Notification. when I am editing a block in the admin backend, I get the following error in developer tools and I cannot save/update any changes.

In Chrome:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'serviceWorker' property from 'Navigator': Service worker is disabled because the context is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
    at U (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mirasvit_PushNotification/js/lib/firebase.js:105:22300)
    at new V (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mirasvit_PushNotification/js/lib/firebase.js:105:19725)
    at firebase.INTERNAL.registerService.Messaging [as messaging] (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mirasvit_PushNotification/js/lib/firebase.js:105:22828)
    at X.S (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mirasvit_PushNotification/js/lib/firebase.js:24:7959)
    at Object.c [as messaging] (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mirasvit_PushNotification/js/lib/firebase.js:24:9342)
    at Object.initialize (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mirasvit_PushNotification/js/subscriber.js:3:25)
    at https://domain.com/admin_meq3as/pagebuilder/stage/render/key/49d2f5c93f9a1aa614e03b15665de84fa0daa3909a11ef063a20f1ba67a51870/?stageId=G6BKUMV:36:20
    at Object.execCb (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:114:132)
    at Module.check (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:56:457)
    at Module.<anonymous> (https://domain.com/static/version1654251240/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:73:103)
```

In Firefox:

```
https://domain.com/push_notification/action/subscribe
CORS Missing Allow Origin
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://domain.com/push_notification/action/subscribe. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 401.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://domain.com/push_notification/action/subscribe. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue related to browser or server configuration
Please try to check [Can't find serviceWorker in navigator anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299246/cant-find-serviceworker-in-navigator-anymore)

Comment: I have tried with IE Edge, Firefox and Chrome and all of them give error. I have update the question with Firefox Dev Tools Error too. Sites, both Dev Environment and Pre production are served through https. If it's a server configuration where should I look? Nginx, Varnish...

Comment: Unfortunately, it's paid extension and i cannot check source code. Try to check headers of `https://domain.com/push_notification/action/subscribe` first

Comment: I found that running Chrome disabling same origin policy removes the error but that's a workaround. "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security". Looking at the response headers I get: access-control-allow-origin *, cache-control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, cache-control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN, x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: Try to use curl for `curl https://domain.com/push_notification/action/subscribe -X OPTIONS  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" -H "Origin: https://domain.com" -I`

Comment: HTTP/2 204 
content-type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
x-cache: MISS
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-max-age: 1728000
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since
strict-transport-security: max-age=7889238
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC

Comment: Headers looks correct. Do you have valid SSL, etc? Is request made from HTTPS to HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, SSL was issued with Let's Encrypt. I don't think http is used in between